# QT installation on Mac

Tags: qt, macos, path, installation, installation-path

want to know if it is adviseable to install the Qt SDK in the Developer/SDKs folder. I wanted to put it in there but I get the following warning:
You have selected an existing, non-empty folder for installation.
Note that it will be completely wiped on uninstallation of this application.
It is not advisable to install into this folder as installation might fail.
Do you want to continue?

Where is the best place to put it. I had QT SDK installed earlier, but while compiling some examples he couldnt find the header files. The installation guide from trolltech is a bit confusing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing that message from the Qt SDK installer is that it expects you to append a new folder name to the path. The default installation location for the Qt SDK is

~/QtSDK

If you wanted to place it in Developer/SDKs, you should enter

/Developer/SDKs/QtSDK

The /Developer/SDKs folder is the normal location for Mac OS X SDKs, as used by Xcode and the GNU toolchain. Xcode looks inside subfolders of /Developer/SDKs to populate the list of available SDKs in the Base SDK project setting, so I would avoid placing Qt here and leave that location for Mac system SDKs.

Comment: Is it ok to install it under Developer/QtSDK? Do I have to do something after this installation(adding library/configuration and so on?)I am sorry that I am asking but, the last time i installed it everything seemed fine but couldnt run the examples(especielly the hellogl example)